# Find appropriate value from table

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013, vba

[image]

I have below table in Excel. I want to display appropriate value in "**C9**" from table. User can only change value of **C7** and **C8**.
I am using =IF(AND(),) statement but it is way too long. Can you suggest me any other formula that I can use. I have tried VLOOKUP but it didn't work. 
Can I use INDEX and MATCH together? 
Can you guide me on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably better on superuser.com but the best way to do this is to learn to use index and match functions.

```
=index($B$2:$F$5,match(c8,$a$2:$a$5,0),match(c7,$B$1:$F$1,0))
```

Index takes an array and the row and column index you want.

Match returns which cell the value is in an array.

So match(c8...) returns 1 since it is the first value in the array.

After the matches are done it becomes

```
=index($B$2:$F$5,1,1)
```

Which means take the first row and first column of that array.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following formula:

```
=VLOOKUP(C8, A1:F5, MATCH(C7, A1:F1, 0), FALSE)
```

Hereby using the `MATCH()` function to return information about what column index to use in the `VLOOKUP()`.